# Programmatically reading messages from systemd's journal

Tags: php, linux, systemd

### Update, 2013-09-12:

I've dug a bit deeper into `systemd` and it's `journal`, and, I've stumbled upon [this](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.socket.html), that states:

> `systemd-journald` will forward all received log messages to the `AF_UNIX SOCK_DGRAM` socket `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`, if it exists, which may be used by Unix syslog daemons to process the data further.

As per manpage, I did set up my environment to also have syslog underneath, I've tweaked my code accordingly:

```
define('NL', "\n\r");

$log = function ()
{
    if (func_num_args() >= 1)
    {
        $message = call_user_func_array('sprintf', func_get_args());

        echo '[' . date('r') . '] ' . $message . NL; 
    }
};

$syslog = '/var/run/systemd/journal/syslog';

$sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
$connection = socket_connect($sock, $syslog);

if (!$connection)
{
    $log('Couldn\'t connect to ' . $syslog);
}
else
{
    $log('Connected to ' . $syslog);

    $readables = array($sock);

    socket_set_nonblock($sock);

    while (true)
    {
        $read = $readables;
        $write = $readables;
        $except = $readables;

        $select = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0);

        $log('Changes: %d.', $select);
        $log('-------');
        $log('Read: %d.', count($read));
        $log('Write: %d.', count($write));
        $log('Except: %d.', count($except));

        if ($select > 0)
        {
            if ($read)
            {
                foreach ($read as $readable)
                {
                    $data = socket_read($readable, 4096, PHP_BINARY_READ);

                    if ($data === false)
                    {
                        $log(socket_last_error() . ': ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
                    }
                    else if (!empty($data))
                    {
                        $log($data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $log('Read empty.');
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($write)
            {
                foreach ($write as $writable)
                {
                    $data = socket_read($writable, 4096, PHP_BINARY_READ);

                    if ($data === false)
                    {
                        $log(socket_last_error() . ': ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
                    }
                    else if (!empty($data))
                    {
                        $log($data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $log('Write empty.');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This apparently, only sees (selects) changes on `write` sockets. Well, might be that something here is wrong so I attempted to read from them, no luck (nor there should be):

> `[Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:45:15 +0300] Changes: 1.`
>   `[Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:45:15 +0300] -------`
>   `[Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:45:15 +0300] Read: 0.`
>   `[Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:45:15 +0300] Write: 1.`
>   `[Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:45:15 +0300] Except: 0.`
>   `[Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:45:15 +0300] 11: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Now, this drives me nuts a little. `syslog` documentation says this should be possible. What is wrong with the code?

### Original:

I had a working prototype, by simply:

```
while(true)
{
    exec('journalctl -r -n 1 | more', $result, $exit);

    // do stuff
}
```

But this feels wrong, and consumes too much system resources, then I found out about journald having sockets.

I have attempted to connect and read from:

```
AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM : /var/run/systemd/journal/socket
AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM : /var/run/systemd/journal/stdout
```

the given sockets.

With `/var/run/systemd/journal/socket`, `socket_select` sees 0 changes. With `/var/run/systemd/journal/stdout` I always (every loop) get 1 change, with 0 byte data.

This is my "reader":

```
<?php

define('NL', "\n\r");

$journal = '/var/run/systemd/journal/socket';
$jSTDOUT = '/var/run/systemd/journal/stdout';

$journal = $jSTDOUT;

$sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$connection = @socket_connect($sock, $journal);

$log = function ($message)
{
    echo '[' . date('r') . '] ' . $message . NL; 
};

if (!$connection)
{
    $log('Couldn\'t connect to ' . $journal);
}
else
{
    $log('Connected to ' . $journal);

    $readables = array($sock);

    while (true)
    {
        $read = $readables;

        if (socket_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 0) < 1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($read as $read_socket)
        {
            $data = @socket_read($read_socket, 1024, PHP_BINARY_READ);

            if ($data === false)
            {
                $log('Couldn\'t read.');

                socket_shutdown($read_socket, 2);
                socket_close($read_socket);

                $log('Server terminated.');
                break 2;
            }

            $data = trim($data);

            if (!empty($data))
            {
                $log($data);
            }
        }
    }

    $log('Exiting.');
}
```

Having no data in read socket(s), I assume I'm doing something wrong.

### Question, idea:

My goal is to read the messages and upon some of them, execute a *callback*.

Could anyone point me into the right direction of how to programmatically read journal messages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sockets under `/run/systemd/journal/` won't work for this – `…/socket` and `…/stdout` are actually write-only (i.e. used for feeding data *into* the journal) while the `…/syslog` socket is not supposed to be used by anything else than a real syslogd, not to mention journald does not send any metadata over it. (In fact, the `…/syslog` socket doesn't even exist by default – syslogd must actually listen on it, and journald connects to it.)

The official method is to read directly from the **journal files**, and use **inotify** to watch for changes (which is the same thing `journalctl --follow` and even `tail -f /var/log/syslog` use in place of polling). In a C program, you can use the functions from [libsystemd-journal](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-journal.html), which will do the necessary parsing and even filtering for you.

In other languages, you have three choices: call the C library; parse the journal files yourself (the format is [documented](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/journal-files/)); or fork `journalctl --follow` which can be told to output [JSON-formatted](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/json/) entries (or the more verbose [journal export](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/export/) format). The third option actually works very well, since it only forks a single process for the entire stream; I have written a PHP wrapper for it (see below).

Recent systemd versions ([v193](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-September/006738.html)) also come with **[`systemd-journal-gatewayd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-gatewayd.service.html)**, which is essentially a HTTP-based version of `journalctl`; that is, you can get a JSON or journal-export stream at `http://localhost:19531/entries`. (Both *gatewayd* and *journalctl* even support [server-sent events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) for accessing the stream from HTML 5 webpages.) However, due to obvious security issues, *gatewayd* is disabled by default.

---

Attachment: PHP wrapper for `journalctl --follow`

```
<?php
/* © 2013 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>
 * Released under the MIT Expat License <https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT>
 */

/* Iterator extends Traversable {
    void    rewind()
    boolean valid()
    void    next()
    mixed   current()
    scalar  key()
}
calls:  rewind, valid==true, current, key
    next, valid==true, current, key
    next, valid==false
*/

class Journal implements Iterator {
    private $filter;
    private $startpos;
    private $proc;
    private $stdout;
    private $entry;

    static function _join_argv($argv) {
        return implode(" ",
            array_map(function($a) {
                return strlen($a) ? escapeshellarg($a) : "''";
            }, $argv));
    }

    function __construct($filter=[], $cursor=null) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->startpos = $cursor;
    }

    function _close_journal() {
        if ($this->stdout) {
            fclose($this->stdout);
            $this->stdout = null;
        }
        if ($this->proc) {
            proc_close($this->proc);
            $this->proc = null;
        }
        $this->entry = null;
    }

    function _open_journal($filter=[], $cursor=null) {
        if ($this->proc)
            $this->_close_journal();

        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->startpos = $cursor;

        $cmd = ["journalctl", "-f", "-o", "json"];
        if ($cursor) {
            $cmd[] = "-c";
            $cmd[] = $cursor;
        }
        $cmd = array_merge($cmd, $filter);
        $cmd = self::_join_argv($cmd);

        $fdspec = [
            0 => ["file", "/dev/null", "r"],
            1 => ["pipe", "w"],
            2 => ["file", "/dev/null", "w"],
        ];

        $this->proc = proc_open($cmd, $fdspec, $fds);
        if (!$this->proc)
            return false;
        $this->stdout = $fds[1];
    }

    function seek($cursor) {
        $this->_open_journal($this->filter, $cursor);
    }

    function rewind() {
        $this->seek($this->startpos);
    }

    function next() {
        $line = fgets($this->stdout);
        if ($line === false)
            $this->entry = false;
        else
            $this->entry = json_decode($line);
    }

    function valid() {
        return ($this->entry !== false);
        /* null is valid, it just means next() hasn't been called yet */
    }

    function current() {
        if (!$this->entry)
            $this->next();
        return $this->entry;
    }

    function key() {
        if (!$this->entry)
            $this->next();
        return $this->entry->__CURSOR;
    }
}

$a = new Journal();

foreach ($a as $cursor => $item) {
    echo "================\n";
    var_dump($cursor);
    //print_r($item);
    if ($item)
        var_dump($item->MESSAGE);
}
```